# Django: Cache needs to de deleted to see new design changes

Tags: django, kubernetes, browser-cache, nginx-ingress

I have a Django applciation running in kubernetes environment behind an nginx ingress controller. Often when I redeploy the app with new design changes, the browser history/cache needs to be deleted in order to see the changes. How to automate this process so the user does not need to delete the browser cache to see the latest changes?

Comment: You need to look for cache busting mechanisms.

Comment: Do you have any examples for that?